# Django TypeError missing 1 required positional argument when trying to use form input in another function

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm really a noob.

What I'm trying to do is to use an input (a category to display) from a ModelForm and pass it to another function, which would render a table accordingly on the next page.

Here is the first function from my views.py

```
def index(request):
    form1 = PrimarySearchForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_valid():
        return results(request, form1.cleaned_data['actor'])
    template = 'main/index.html'
    context = {'form1': form1}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here is the second function from views.py

```
def results(request, actor):
    table = FactTable(Sawn_Areas_Fact.objects.get(actors=actor))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'main/results.html', {'table': table})
```

Here is the form
    class PrimarySearchForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Actors_Dim
    fields = ('actor',)
```

So, when I run the server, select an entry and click submit I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'actor'
[29/Jul/2018 17:10:04] "POST /results/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59914
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you add your urls.py?

Comment: What is FactTable. Show code.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge here is my urls.py: 
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^results/', views.results, name='results'),
]

Comment: Are you sure that `form1.cleaned_data['actor']` holds correct value?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes. The problem was in the template in the form action: it was posting to the wrong page. As I said - I'm completely a noob :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you claim it is. The log shows that your form is not posting to the index view at all; it is posting to the results view. This is certainly because that is what you have put in the action attribute of the form tag in the template.

Actually, you shouldn't be doing either of these; you should be posting to index, but then *redirecting* to results when the form is valid.

Comment: Thank you!  In the template, I've changed the form action and it helped! I still don't use redirect in the first function, but now its working as intended

Answer (score 0):

is the actor field required in the `ModelForm`? `form1.cleaned_data['actor']` returns an empty string that's why you get this error. Make a print statement and check if form1.cleaned_data['actor'] is returning a string as expected.

Comment: Yes, the field is required and it's not empty - it returns a string.